# How to remove background blue color that pops up and goes when the switch(html toggle switch using checkbox) is clicked? (Solution found)

Tags: html, css, checkbox

### This is my html code for the switch

```
            <div class="switch-container">
                <p>Value1</p>
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
                <p>Value2</p>
            </div>
```

### This is how the element is styled in css file

```
/* 
-----------Switch---------
 */
.switch-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
}

/* It contains the actual switch */
.switch{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide the square box */
.switch input{
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* The slider inside which the circle moves */
.slider{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 34px;
}


/* The moving circle inside the slider */
.slider::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height:26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .4s;
}


/* Give the color when selected */
input:checked + .slider{
    background-color: #2196f3;
}

input:focus + .slider{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196f3;
}


/* Move the ball on click */
input:checked + .slider:before{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px)
}
```

### Problem :

When the switch is clicked there is a blue box which pops up and goes away behind the switch. I already tried to set outline as none but its not working.

How to remove the background blue tint that pops up when the switch is clicked ?

### Solution :

The code provided by me is working perfectly. Sometimes when you view your website in google chromes responsive view in developers tools then the site may show some unexpected behaviour. This is because it shows you step by step load of your website and not the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
input:checked + .slider{
    background-color: #2196f3;
box-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found out that if you preview your page in chromes developers tools and make the page responsive, then some unexpected behavior happens. The same was the case for me.

The website was working fine out of the developer tools.